# Velocity of one particle w.r.t. another

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, relative-motion

Let us say that two particles $p_1$ and $p_2$ are moving in an inertial frame fixed to some point on earth. Call this frame as world frame. The velocity of $p_1$ is $(v_{1x}, v_{1y})$ in $x-y $ direction of this frame. Similarly the velocity of $p_2$ is $(v_{2x}, v_{2y})$.  I want to compute the direction of motion i.e. heading of $p_2$ w.r.t. $p_1$. Which of these two methods is correct:

1. Compute the heading of $p_2$ and $p_1$ in world frame. Call this $\psi_2 = atan2(v_{2y}, v_{2x})$ and $\psi_1 = atan2(v_{1y}, v_{1x})$. Then the heading of $p_2$ w.r.t. $p_1$ is $\psi = \left(\psi_2 - \psi_1\right)$.
2. Compute the velocity of $p_2$ w.r.t. $p_1$ as $(v_{2x}-v_{1x}, v_{2y}-v_{1y})$. Relative heading is then $\psi = atan2(v_{2y}-v_{1y}, v_{2x}-v_{1x})$.

Answer (score 1):

You can convince yourself that the first method does not work in general by looking at a simple example. Take the two objects moving with constant headings in the world frame, starting from the origin. For example one moving north and the other east, first with constant velocity and the second accelerating. So the diffference between their headings in the world frame is a constant (90 degrees in this case). But the heading of one in the frame of the other changes as they move farther apart from the origin.

Answer (score 0):

The relative velocity of $p_2$ with respect to $p_1$ is simply
$$\vec{v_{21}} = \vec{v_2}-\vec{v_1}$$
Simply calculate the difference between the two vectors as done in the second method as the first method is inconvenient and not a general method. If the two points happen to be accelerating, then the first method will cause unnecessary complications. Moreover, you need to find the angle twice, which isn't easy.